# Two buttons in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios

I have a problem with button in UITableViewCell. Please help me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 2:{
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                    // Make backgroung invisible
                    [self cellBackground:cell];
                    // Make the save button
                    [self saveButton:cell];

                    [self showButton:cell];

                }
                break;

        }
    } 
    return cell;
}
- (void)saveButton:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    UIButton *saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    saveButton.frame = CGRectMake(45, 0, 300, 45);
    saveButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    saveButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,0);

    [cell addSubview:saveButton];
}

- (void)showButton:(UITableViewCell *)cell{
    UIButton *showButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [showButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    showButton.frame = CGRectMake(45, 0, 300, 45);
    showButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
    showButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,0);

    [cell addSubview:showButton];
 }
```

I just want to have saveButton and showButton side by side in the indexPath.section = 2, and the size of button should fit the size of cell in landscape or portrait. Do you know how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this completely wrong. I won't go over the general parts but you should definitely subclass `UITableViewCell` and add `saveButton` and `showButton` as methods of the subclass and run those when the class is initiated.

And add them to `cell.contentView`. Not to `cell`!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are building those cells wrong:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

this can return nil so you should check:

```
 if(!cell) { 
      //construct new cell here.
 }
```

For handling both rotation best it to place button.frame.origin.x = cell.view.frame.width - 10.0f and set anchor to right side of button.

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: won't return nil. From Apple Docs: This method returns a UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell.

Comment: Ok I don't see registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: - so I didn't think it's with indexPath parameter.